# Stream join result default value

Tags: java

If I join a couple of string via streams and there is nothing to join the result is an empty string like "". Is there a possibility to add a default value in case it is empty? E.g. "-"

```
someList.stream()
                .filter(a -> a.getKey() != null)
                .map(a -> a.getKey())
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Update:
I know there are other ways to do it but I just wanted to know if the default value of "" (empty string) can be overriden

Comment: why just not add a test like `if (outString.isEmpty()) return "-";`

Comment: I could but I just wondered if it is possible

Comment: just add the check after you've generated the string.

Comment: How about using Optional:`String string = Optional.of(someList.stream()...).orElse("-");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String result = someList.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getKey() != null)
        .map(a -> a.getKey())
        .sorted()
        .reduce((a,b) -> a + ", " + b).orElse("-");
```

where we use reduce instead of collect.

EDIT: First solution was indeed not working as expected. This one is.

Comment: This will not work, as for 2 elements it will return "-A,B,"

Answer (score 1):

why just not add a test like `if (outString.isEmpty()) return "-";`

Just after your code

```
String outString = someList.stream()
            .filter(a -> a.getKey() != null)
            .map(a -> a.getKey())
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); 

if (outString.isEmpty()) 
   return "-";
else 
   return outString;
```